# How do you execute a template with 500 status code in Go?

Tags: go, web-applications

I know that I can execute template with:

```
t.ParseFiles(name)
t.Execute(w, page)
```

And respond 500 with a message like this:

```
http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
```

But how should I return 500 with a template that contains that message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [`ResponseWriter.WriteHeader`](https://godoc.org/net/http#ResponseWriter) before you execute your template:

> WriteHeader sends an HTTP response header with status code.
>   If WriteHeader is not called explicitly, the first call to Write
>   will trigger an implicit WriteHeader(http.StatusOK).
>   Thus explicit calls to WriteHeader are mainly used to send error codes.

```
t.ParseFiles(name)
w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
t.Execute(w, page)
```

If you look at the [source code of `http.Error`](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go#L1951), you can see it's doing the same thing.